# How to apply magento 1 MPERF-10509 patch

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, patch

I was trying to apply a Magento patch but I got confused when I saw the extension of the file ending on .diff so I tried to use the command diff, sh or bash without any luck.

How can I apply Magento patch `MPERF-10509-CE-2019-03-13-06-31-24.diff`

Comment: Have you read reference of how to do this from the source page you receive patch ?

Answer (score 3):

If someone has a problem in the installation the patch for Magento 1 MPERF-10509, here is the way how it was successfully applied to my store.

```
server@store:/var/www/magento$ patch -p1 <  MPERF-10509-CE-2019-03-13-06-31-24.diff 
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 37 (offset 18 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 98 (offset 18 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 192 (offset 18 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 268 (offset 18 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 318 (offset 18 lines).
server@store:/var/www/magento$
```